# Add overlay to captured image and recorded videos in Android CameraX

Tags: android, camera, overlay

In my project I need to overlay a captured picture or a recorded video with some sensor values in Android CameraX (Beta). Overlaying the preview works fine but I also need to overlay the values when I'm recording or capturing. I know that recording videos is still a restricted use case in cameraX at the moment but I'd already be happy to add the overlay to the captured images. Looking at the docs and the posts I dont't have any idea where to start. Maybe someone can give me some hints where to start with the developement!

Comment: Using only CameraX, I'm not sure if that'd be possible. It might be doable if you use the preview use case, your own surface and openGL. Otherwise, an easier approach would be to capture the image or video with CameraX, then use something like ffmpeg to overlay an image on top of either.

Comment: Thx - right out of my mood I'll start to deal with ffmpeg… Hope to come back with some code samples ;-)